# Property 'dataSource' not found on object of type 'QLPreviewController *' error in Objective-C

Tags: ios, objective-c, quicklook

I got this problem from this patch of code:

```objectivec
- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewDidAppear:animated];
    
    /*
     *  get the path to the pdf resource.
     */
    
    NSString *path =
    [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"article"
                                    ofType:@"pdf"];
    NSURL *docURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:path];
    
    
    /*
     *  create the Quicklook controller.
     */
    QLPreviewController *qlController = [[QLPreviewController alloc] init];
    
    PreviewItem *item =
    [[PreviewItem alloc] initPreviewURL:docURL
                              WithTitle:@"Article"];
    self.pdfDatasource =
    [[PDFDataSource alloc] initWithPreviewItem:item];
    
    qlController.dataSource = self.pdfDatasource;
    
    
    /*
     *  present the document.
     */
    
    [self presentViewController:qlController
                       animated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

The line that was causing the problem is the line:

```objectivec
qlController.dataSource = self.pdfDataSource
```

Also, the iOS app I was trying to make is one that utilizes a QuickLook framework to display a document, if that helps anyone.

I got the code from a guide [here](https://medium.com/ios-os-x-development/ios-using-quicklook-for-fun-and-profit-d9a338e2f7fb).
Any help?

*P.S. I can't switch to Swift yet for some reasons, so I'll just keep my app as Objective-C for now.*

Comment: I followed the article you linked to -- and it seems to work fine. Are you getting a run-time error? Or are you saying it won't compile because of this line `qlController.dataSource = self.pdfDataSource`?

Comment: @DonMag It just straight up errored out when I was editing the code.

Comment: OK - did you follow that complete example? In this question, you only show 1 of the 5 code sections...

Comment: Yes, I did, just that I just copied the portion of the code that was causing the error, not the entire thing....

Comment: Well, difficult to say where your code is wrong if you don't post your code. Try this: create a brand new project... add "article.pdf" to the bundle... replace the default `ViewController.m` with this: https://pastebin.com/81qwjbqj  --- it will show the preview controller on tap, instead of in `viewDidAppear`